# What is the meaning of '|e' in RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

In the line below, what is the purpose of the '|e'? I tried looking it up but couldn't find it, and the line still does what it's supposed to when it isn't there.

```
pattern = /([\+|\-]?[\d]+[\.][\d|\-|e]+)[ ]+([\+|\-]?[\d]+[\.][\d|\-|e]+)[ ]+([\+|\-]?[\d]+[\.][\d|\-|e]+)/g;
```

EDIT:

Here is a sample of what the code is parsing.

```
-3.424999 -0.855454 2.257396 
-1.484919 0.665606 -3.151304 
1.636841 -0.848154 -0.458954 
3.732041 0.187906 -1.319734 
-1.756719 0.682006 0.807596 
0.911641 -0.828054 3.040696 
-0.218059 -0.489374 -3.806524 
-1.078099 0.891706 -2.420454
```

Comment: This pattern is strange. It doesn't seem optimal. I doubt it works as intended.

Comment: What's the goal of that regex?

Comment: The code is from Mr. Doob's VTKLoader.js. It takes in a VTK file and parses it.

Comment: Isn't the `|` just an `or`?

Comment: `e` is  one of possible characters from the group

Comment: `[\d|\-|e]+` means  a digit or a pipe or a dash or a pipe or a "e", at least once.

Comment: looks like the regex is looking for scientific notation (+3.1234-e)...

Comment: All characters in a character class (indicated by `[ ]` square brackets) are implicitly _OR_ 'ed. Exception's are (escaped constructs) like `\xFF` or `\009` and operators like the dash 'from`-`to'  which means a range of characters, and the operator '[^ ]` negative (very beginning of class) meaning all chars _NOT_ in the class. The dash can be escaped to mean literal char and the  caret can be escaped (or not in the first position)  to mean literal. Some engines have other control chars used inside classes. The pipe `|` is just a character like any other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, A `|` gives alternative options, so `(one|two)` matches either one or two.

However putting `|` inside the `[]` suggests that someone doesn't understand how the `[]` work (they match a single instance of any character within them - or a range, so `[a-z]` matches a or b or c...

I suspect, unless you have `|` within the string you are matching, then you can remove all of the `|` occurences from the pattern and it will still work. But it's difficult to know more without seeing some examples of the kind of string it should be matching, and what you want to capture.

*(edit)*: Now you have provided a sample, if I was parsing that, I would use something like

```
/([+-]?\d+\.\d+)\s([+-]?\d+\.\d+)\s([+-]?\d+\.\d+)/
```

If you want to be able to accept numbers of the form 1.234e56 this would change to

```
/([+-]?\d+\.\d+(e[+-]?\d+)?)\s([+-]?\d+\.\d+(e[+-]?\d+)?)\s([+-]?\d+\.\d+(e[+-]?\d+)?)/
```

(The above assumes there will always be a decimal point)

Comment: Putting `|` *twice* inside a `[]` group almost certainly indicates confusion.

Answer (score 1):

`[\d|\-|e]` seems weird: it's digit or a pipe or a dash or a pipe or e. It's useless to put the pipe twice.

I think this should be `[\d\-e]` if the purpose was to allow digit, dash or e but not pipe.